# Launch two or more Google Chrome apps on login, preferably minimized/hidden

Tags: google-chrome, ventura, login-items

I'm using macOS Ventura and I'd like to launch both Gmail and Google Calendar apps on startup/login.

Both apps were "installed" via Chrome's **Create Shortcut...** option that essentially creates an .app that opens a lite Chrome window with a predefined URL.

My issue is that when I try adding both apps to Login items only one gets added, and the other is ignored, as if it already exists in the list or something, even though the name, icons, and the actual .app file are different.

As a bonus, I'd prefer if both apps were to start minimized or hidden, as most of the time I only need them for desktop notifications, but I can't find the "Hidden" checkbox in Login Items that some of the sites/blogs mention.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I was able to achieve opening both chrome shortcuts on login by utilizing the macOS shortcuts app.

I created a new shortcut which used the 'open file' action to open each different chrome shortcut.  After saving that shortcut I r-clicked on it in the shortcuts app and selected 'add to dock' which of course adds this shortcut to your macOS dock.  On that new dock icon again r-click and select  'Options > Open at Login'.  Now on login that shortcut will execute which opens the chrome shortcuts.

I am not sure how to launch them minimized however.